# Passing IEnumerable<Object> to ViewModel - Does Object need to be ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

Getting my head around MVC today and ran across the best practice of not passing a Model directly to a view.  Instead, use a ViewModel.

I researched AutoMapper and plan on using it to map my ViewModels to the respective Models.  And I understand that AutoMapper is smart enough to map IEnumerable to IEnumerable without a separate mapping, as long as source and dest are mapped.

But I'm a bit confused about how to handle passing an IEnumerable in my ViewModel to my view.  I currently have my page working using a ViewModel that includes IEnumerable but I read that this is just as bad as passing the IEnumerable directly to the view.  So do I need a separate ViewModel to hold the object which will be used in an IEnumerable property of the main ViewModel?

So where Activity is the Model in question:

```cs
public class ActivityHistoryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Activity> activities { get; set; }
}
```

do I need to create ActivityViewModel and write my ActivityHistoryViewModel like this?

```cs
public class ActivityHistoryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel> activities { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Assuming the only data your model will need is the list, then you don't really need `ActivityHistoryViewModel` and the view can be typed as such:

```
@model IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel>
```

your auto mapper config would look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Activity, ActivityViewModel>();
```

you would map like this:

```
IEnumerable<Activity> data = GetActivities();
var model = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Activity>, IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel>>(data);
return View(model);
```

And when you define `ActivityViewModel` you can either create a property-for-property duplicate type, or trim out the excess data you don't need (in my case it would be something like "created date", that is db generated and of no importance to users).

**Or** if you want to stick with `ActivityHistoryViewModel` to pass along more than just the list:

view type:

```
@model ActivityHistoryViewModel
```

mapping config can remain the same

map like this:

```
IEnumerable<Activity> data = GetActivities();
var model = new ActivityHistoryViewModel() {
    someOtherProperty = "hello world!",
    activities = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Activity>, IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel>>(data)
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: Duh, didn't even think of passing the IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel>. But I really was thinking of the bigger scenario where I would need to pass along additional data.

Comment: I added code to use `ActivityHistoryViewModel` instead. Hope its what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, I managed to get everything working, including a custom mapping to a property on a nested entity object. I appreciate your help. It always becomes easy once you figure it out. :)

Comment: as an addition there is also ValueInjecter (doesnt require setting up mappings first) and also you can use the [AutoMap()] attribute from Jimmy Bogard (make of automapper) to automatically do the map when you return "Activity" it would map to ActivityViewModel based on the attribute constructor